# Using d3js to build table with multiple rows in thead where some cells have mixed colspan widths

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3noob's "Add a Table" tutorial to get most of the table, but I can't figure out how to get the thead cells laid out the way I want.

I'm pretty sure I'm screwing up on the first thead.append block, but if I remove ".data(columns)," I just get a white page.

Thanks for the help!

---

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Get the data
d3.tsv("data/data2.tsv",function(error,data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date1 = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    d.open = +d.open;
    d.diff = Math.round(( d.close - d.open ) * 100 ) / 100;
});

// Time to make the tables
function tabulate(data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select("body").append("table").attr("class", "graph-key"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

        // What the hell?
        thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .attr("colspan", "2")
        .text("Stuff Here");

        // Append the header row
        thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function (column) {
            return column;
        });

    // Create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // Create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {
                    column: column,
                    value: row[column]
                };
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .html(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
        return table;
}

// Render the table
var peopleTable = tabulate(data, ["date", "close", "open", "diff"]);
});
```

Comment: What do you want to have as theader? You're currently appending two of them.

Comment: I'm trying to get something like this:

`<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Foo</th>
<th colspan="3">Bar</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
</tr>
</thead>`

Comment: I can't figure out how to get D3 to render the mixed colspan widths.

Comment: You would need to make that part of your data somehow so that you can switch on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified tabulate that does what you want and an example call as per your comment.

This tabulate takes a header parameter which is an Array of Arrays of objects with names and optional spans.

```
// Time to make the tables
function tabulate(data, header) {
    var table = d3.select("body").append("table").attr("class", "graph-key"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    thead.selectAll("tr")
        .data(header)
        .enter()
        .append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
            .data(function(d) {return d;})
            .enter()
            .append("th")
            .attr("colspan", function(d) {return d.span;})
            .text(function(d) {return d.name;});

    // Create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // Create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {
                    column: column,
                    value: row[column]
                };
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .html(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });
    return table;
}

// Render the table
var peopleTable = tabulate(data, [
    [{name: "Foo", span: 2}, {name: "Bar", span: 3}], 
    [{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}, {name: "5"}]
]);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Now I'm getting a different error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined." I think it has to do with columns in the tbody not being defined correctly. I'll create a new post if I can't figure it out.

Thanks again for the help, Ray.